# Slice some element array

Tags: php, arrays

can you show me, how create a new array every second keys with this  same keys as in the original array?
Input

```
$product_shop=[1=>200,5=>150, 10=>343, 2=>654, 6=>333]
```

i need  output

```
$product_shop=[1=>200, 10=>343, 6=>333]
```

I can't sort keys.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Ofcourse, but i  can't find a solution.

http://pastebin.com/EZdhQb3C

I don't  know  how i can  use prev and next key because this keys are differense and we can't  e.g $products_shop[$i]

Comment: Then add your ^ attempt(s) into your question. It can only help, that we exactly see where you got stuck and show you what you did wrong and how to do it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's correct way

```
$product_shop=[1=>200,5=>150, 10=>343, 2=>654, 6=>333];
$second_array = [];
$i = 0;
foreach ($product_shop as $key=>$value) {
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
        $second_array[$key] = $value;
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: Mind that if running php < 5.4 the "[]" will fail. In that case use "array()"

Comment: I know, but @Pekus gave example with [];

Comment: looooollll, i spent this problem about 2 hour.. i think need to relax.   Thank you! 
And i use php >5.4 :)

Comment: I didn't down vote, i was merely mentioning it for posterity.

Comment: Can you show me yet, how compare elements  second_array  with prev value product_array? e.g
        if(products_array[5] >=second_array[10])  
      if(products_array[2] >=second_array[6])      something... else  other something etc..

This doesn't work ;

http://pastebin.com/tEAGuVYb

Answer (score 1):

next time give some some examples of what you've tried:

```
<?php
$even = array();
$odd = array();
$i = 0;
foreach($product_shop as $key => $value){
    if($i++%2===0){
        $even[$key] = $value;
    } else {
        $odd[$key] = $value;
    }
}
var_dump($even, $odd); exit;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$product_shop=[1=>200,5=>150, 10=>343, 2=>654, 6=>333];

$i = 0;
$array = array_filter($product_shop, function ($e) use (&$i) {
    return ++$i & 1;
});
```

This will print:

```
array(3) {
  [1]=>
  int(200)
  [10]=>
  int(343)
  [6]=>
  int(333)
}
```

Comment: Imho a bit too complex answer for a newbie but +1 nevertheless

Comment: What's complex? I will add some detail if something is not clear

Comment: It's just that imho your answer used various concepts which are not likely to be familiar or easy to understand to someone who asks the sort of question OP asked,